# Show connected printers in CUPS

Tags: linux, command-line, printing, cups, c++

Is there a way to list the available/connected printers in CUPS using the command line or better yet using the CUPS API ?

I already tried `lpstat -a` but it only lists the installed printers and not the available ones!

Using the API I run into the same problem with `cupsGetDests()`

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can run `lpinfo -v` and it will show you what's actually plugged in. As for getting a list of what's plugged in AND installed.. I think I have to compare the output of `lpinfo` to the output of `lpstat -v` or something.